# SQLite3, UTF-8, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, sqlite

I've created an SQLite3 database in a Cocoa Objective-C project. The data comprises strings of Japanese characters so I need the database to be saved in UTF-8 format.

How do I tell SQLite3 to adopt the UTF-8 encoding? Or is SQLite3 intelligent enough to set this once it has received a UTF-8 encoded string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the section on "Support for UTF-8 and UTF-16" in:

http://www.sqlite.org/version3.html

It looks like the default behavior is what you want.